# How to prevent nginx rewriting again after adding index file?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write some nginx rewrite rules for a web server, and one of them is as simple as:

```
index index.html;
...
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /web/$1 break;
```

This rule adds a `/web` before the URI. It works with a query like `www.mydomain.com/somefile` and returns the content of `/docroot/web/somefile`.

However, if I query a `www.mydomain.com/somedir/`, this rule will be applied twice: At first the URI is rewritten to `/web/somedir/`. Then nginx changes it to `/web/somedir/index.html` according to `index index.html`. After this, the rewrite rule will be applied again and gets a URI of `/web/web/somedir/index.html`.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to do a rewrite rule for that, try adding a root in the server.
If this website uses some sort of URL rewrites then you need to add those, if you need help please explain how you want the URLs to be rewritten and I'll help you.

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    root /docroot/web; #make sure to put web
    index index.html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the problem described above is just a simplified example. Actually, I have several other requirements which make it not suitable to change the root.